# Vidoes not playing on ipod

Tags: video, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod

I need to play some movie files in the iphone. For that i have used standard coding, converted the file to m4v format from itunes, and then uploaded the file onto a server, so that i can directly call it through code to download and play on the MpMediaPlayerViewcontroller for OS >3.2 and mpmediaplayercontroller for OS <3.2.

Now the problem, the converted file which i stream from server at runtime plays fine on Iphone 3, 3gs, IOS 4, but it fails to play on the ipod touch(4g)(calling from my program).

The same video, if i sync through itunes directly to the ipod, and play it via the Videos app on The ipod touch(4g), plays flawlessly.

So i am not able to understand, what exactly is going wrong. If any one can, please help me out. Its seriously important.

Please note, i dont change code even a bit except for <3.2 and >3.2 variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it folks... The user agent on the server side got goofed up. :)